# How to test/mock socket.io client

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, socket.io, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock the emit method from io but I don't know how to mock it. This is my `Join.jsx` file

```
//Join.jsx

import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const Join = () => {
  let socket;
  const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';

  const join = () => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit('join', { name: 'Paola', room: '1' }, () => { });
  };

  return (
    <div className="join-container">
        <a className="join-button" onClick={join}>Sign in</a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Join;
```

This is one thing I have tried

```
//Join.test.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Join from './Join';

describe(('Join') => {
  it(('joins a chat') => {
    jest.mock('socket.io-client', () => {
      return jest.fn(() => ({
        emit: jest.fn(),
      }));
    });
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';
    const mockSocket = io(ENDPOINT);
    const joinWrapper = shallow(<Join />);
    joinWrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
    expect(mockSocket.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('join', { name: 'Paola', room: '1' }, () => { });
  })
})
```

This is the error that I get in the terminal

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]

      52 |     const joinWrapper = shallow(<Join />);
      53 |     joinWrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
    > 54 |     expect(mockSocket.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('join', { name: 'Paola', room: '1' }, () => { });
         |                             ^
      55 |   });
      56 | });
      57 |
```

Please don't be rude with your answers, I'm new at testing and I am really lost. Thank you in advance for your responses!!

Comment: Your approach is quite accurate, you just need to move the `jest.mock` block in the scope where you import the library i.e. before the describe block

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with your test code:

1. Move the `jest.mock` code block to module scope. It will be hoisted to the top of the code block. Which means even if you `import Join from './Join'` module first(At the level of code writing order), the `socket.io-client` module will be the mocked version, both for the test file and the file under-tested.
2. Use the same reference of the mocked socket object in the mock factory, otherwise the socket object in the test code and the socket object in the tested code will not be the same reference for every call of `io` function.
3. The anonymous functions is not the same reference as the one in the test code. So the `.toBeCalledWith()` assertion will be failed. Instead, you should use `expect.any(Function)`.

Here is the unit test solution:

`Join.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const Join = () => {
  let socket;
  const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';

  const join = () => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit('join', { name: 'Paola', room: '1' }, () => {});
  };

  return (
    <div className="join-container">
      <a className="join-button" onClick={join}>
        Sign in
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Join;
```

`Join.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Join from './Join';

jest.mock('socket.io-client', () => {
  const mSocket = {
    emit: jest.fn(),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mSocket);
});

describe('Join', () => {
  it('joins a chat', () => {
    const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';
    const mockSocket = io(ENDPOINT);
    const joinWrapper = shallow(<Join />);
    joinWrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
    expect(mockSocket.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('join', { name: 'Paola', room: '1' }, expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63605899/Join.test.tsx
  Join
    ✓ joins a chat (14ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
 Join.tsx |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.162s, estimated 13s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63605899